# perl skip a character from regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string from which I want to remove all control character:

```
$line =~ s/[\000-\037]/ /smg;
```

But here in above regex I want to all control characters except new line.

For example if I have a string like this:

```
Thi **^@** s is an **^M**example **\n** for regex.
```

After applying the regex my text should be like this:

```
This is an example **\n** for regex.
```

Comment: Why you don't use two ranges to exclude the newline?

Answer (score 2):

You may find the `\w` and `\d` macro useful then. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

```
$line =~ s/[^\w\s\n]+//msg;
```

Which will remove anything that *isn't* `word` `whitespace` or `linefeed`.

This approach should extend to solving your problem, although as Borodin notes in the comments:

> "The ASCII set is covered by \p{Cntrl}, \p{Alpha}, \p{Number}, \p{Punct}, \p{Symbol} and the space character. The \s pattern will also include control characters HT, VT, FF and CR,"

So you probably want to factor that in accordingly. (`\w\s\d` won't cover punctuation, for example)

Comment: That will leave out most punctuation (except underscore) and all of the symbols. The ASCII set is covered by `\p{Cntrl}`, `\p{Alpha}`, `\p{Number}`, `\p{Punct}`, `\p{Symbol}` and the space character. The `\s` pattern will also *include* control characters HT, VT, FF and CR, so the OP's example `"Thi **\c@** s is an **\cM**example **\n** for regex."` comes out as `"Thi  s is an \rexample \n for regex"` i.e. it leaves the CR in place and loses all the stars.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove newline `\012` from the character class:

```
[\000-\011\013-\037]
```

If you want to keep also carriage return `\015`:

```
[\000-\011\013\014\016-\037]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Unicode property `Cntrl` to identify control characters, so `/\p{Cntrl}/` will match all control characters.

To exclude linefeed from that range, negate it using `\P` instead of `\p`, add newline and negate it once more with `^`. So

```
/[^\P{cntrl}\n]/
```

will match all control characters except for linefeed.

Note that `\p{Cntrl}` also matches ASCII DEL (`"\x7F"`) and Unicode points `"\x80"` through to `"\x9F"`.